Trouble with reading a file and segregating data into different arrays
I'm attempting to process a file by reading its contents and assigning the data to different arrays based on the number of values per line. However, I'm encountering "index out of bounds" errors. Could you help me verify if my approach aligns with my objective?
Here's an example of the file structure:

2.0 5.0 3.5
5.2 0.5 4.8
1.0
2.5

My goal is to store lines with three numbers in an array called box and lines with a single number in an array called ball. I need to be able to accommodate any number of lines, not just these four.
Below is the code I've written so far:
import java.io.*;

public class MainProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("info.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String nums;
        int count = 0;
        int lineNo = 0;

        while ((nums = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] numbers = nums.split(" ");
            double[][] ball = new double[lineNo][];
            if (numbers.length == 3) {
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    double[][] box = new double[lineNo][i];
                    box[lineNo][i] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[lineNo]);

                    lineNo++;

                    System.out.println(box[i] + " ");
                }
            } else {
                while (numbers.length == 1 && ((nums = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                    int p = 0;
                    ball[count][p] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[count]);
                    p++;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Before I use an object-oriented approach, I'd like to resolve this with basic arrays. Could you assist me with the corrections needed in my code?

Help us help you - can you share the arrays you want to end up with for this input?

NOTE... edited to provide a clearer example based on the community bot suggestion...
Your code says:
double[][] box = new double[lineNo][i];
box[lineNo][i] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[lineNo]);

inside a for loop. the first time through the loop, i is 0...
so your code creates a new array of dimension [lineNo][0]...
and then you try to set box[lineNo][0] value... you cannot use [i] as the index in the second statement because indexes are zero based...
So here is the relevant section of your code, rewritten to address the zero-index:
    int count = 0;
    int lineNo = 0;

    while ((nums = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] numbers = nums.split(" ");
        // do not use ZERO for the first dimension in the declaration...
        // the declaration is the size of the dimension (n),
        // and the zero-based index can only be as high as (n-1)
        double[][] ball = new double[lineNo + 1][]; // size is one higher 
        if (numbers.length == 3) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                // same here... the size has to be one higher
                double[][] box = new double[lineNo+1][i]; 

                // but here it is appropriate to use lineNo starting at zero...
                // that is the index, not the size
                box[lineNo][i] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[lineNo]); 

                lineNo++;

                System.out.println(box[i] + " ");
            }
        } else {
            while (numbers.length == 1 && ((nums = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                int p = 0;
                ball[count][p] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[count]);
                p++;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

With all of that said, you are already using an ArrayList at the top of your code... Lists of Lists allow for hetergeneous filling, but I am trying only to answer the question as you have asked.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The error in your code, part of a feature of the problem, that you have overlooked, “you don't know how many lines you have to process”, this makes the use of two-dimensional arrays, not suitable, we must use something that can grow in size, yes, a list, to be more specific, a list of double arrays, something like:
List<Double[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

in it, we will add the array of double that we are creating
public static void main( String[] args ) {

   // we create the list
   List<Double[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

   // This way, we make sure that the resources are closed.
   try( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( 
           new FileReader( 
                   new File( "src/info.txt" ) ) ); ) {

      String nums;
      while( br.ready() ) {
         nums = br.readLine(); 
         String[] numbers = nums.split( " " );

         // we create the array of "double" and add item's
         Double[] aux = new Double[ numbers.length ];    
         for( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i ++ ) {
            aux[ i ] = Double.valueOf( numbers[ i ] );                
         }
         // add to list the array
         list.add( aux );
      }
   }
   catch( Exception e ) {
      System.out.println( "help" );
   }
   System.out.println( Arrays.deepToString( list.toArray() ) );
}


You can know how many lines to process, before hand. So, you can use arrays only, and not use a List collection. The question post mentions  about using arrays only. How? For example, read the file and count number of rows with 3 numbers and number of rows with one number. Then read the file again to process and populate the appropriate arrays. This is possible. but requires reading the file twice.

@prasad_ Though possible, using an ArrayList as suggested would be more efficient and simpler.
